# In what format do I need Insert 3 table sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012, mysqli

In what format do I need Insert 3 table sql?

```
animals(`AnimalsID`, `Animals`, `IUCN_Red_List`, `TypesID`, `BloodedID`)
types(TypesID,Types)
blooded(BloodedID,Blooded)
```

Comment: Please edit the tags to limit the discussion to either MySQL or SQL Server.  They are different products with different syntax and limitations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not have any syntax that will `INSERT` into 3 different tables with a single SQL statement.

Either do 3 `INSERTs` or encapsulate the 3 Inserts in a Stored procedure, then `CALL` that proc.